# Start steps of how build an ASP.NET Web API that another API which authenticated with cookies and headers login and authorization token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, http-headers, session-cookies

I want to know what are the steps to build ASP.NET Web API to call another API?

In general, the another API that I want to call is built or tested in Postman with authorization with a bearer token and headers as login with username and password, and it's related with cookies consist of client session and other and the response from this API is token generated and the method of this API is post method.

However, what it's the logic from start to build an ASP.NET Web API to call this kind of API ?